# Question regarding singular points of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

> *Definition 1:* The point $z_0$ is called a **singular point** of a function $f$ if $f$ fails to be analytic at $z_0$ but is analytic at some point in every neighborhood of $z_0$
>
> *Definition 2:* A singular point $z_0$ is said to be **isolated** if, in addition,there is a deleted neighborhood of $z_0$ throughout which $f$ is analytic

Example: The function $$\frac{1}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{z})}$$

has the singular points $z=0$ and $z=\frac{1}{n} (n=\pm 1,\pm2,\cdots)$, all lying on the segment of the real axis from $z=-1$ to $z=1$. $\underline{Each\; singular\; point \;except\; z=0 \;is\; isolated.}$

I'm confusing this underlined term, because i know clearly $z=0$ is not an isolated singular point, since every neighborhood of $0$ contains another singular points. This  is ok.

But how the numbers of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ is isolated ? If i take, $n=1000000000000000000000$, then how we guarantee the neighborhood of this  $\frac{1}{n}$ does not contains some remaining singular points ?

I'm sorry, this is very elementary for others, but i'm confusing

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $n,$ the ball of radius $r=\min\{|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}|,|\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}|\}$ centered at $\frac{1}{n}$ has no other singular points.

Comment: Oh! .....I really appreciated! Thanks!